# Evaluating a limit involving parameter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider the following limit which hypothetically uniformly converges to some real analytic function $\Delta$:

$$\Delta_t(x)=\lim_{r\to \infty} \frac{1}{r} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left({\frac{t\log n}{\log r \log x}}\right)$$

I'm looking to evaluate this limit. Here $t > 0$ is some real parameter.

The motivation to find the limit is because it prescribes a controlled deformation of:

$$ \Gamma_t(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left({\frac{t \log n}{\log x}}\right)$$

for real $x\in(0,1).$

I want to be able to conclude that this deformation preserves analyticity.

Conjecturally we have

$$\Delta_t(x)=e^{\frac{t}{\log x}}$$

which is indeed real analytic on $(0,1)$.

> Is $\Delta_t(x)=e^{\frac{t}{\log x}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left({\frac{t\log n}{\log r \log x}}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-{t/(\log r)(\log x^{-1})}} = \zeta\biggl( \frac t{(\log r)(\log x^{-1})} \biggr)
$$
is a value of the Riemann zeta function, but only as long as $t/(\log r)(\log x^{-1})>1$. In particular, once $r \ge \exp(t/\log x^{-1})$, the sum will no longer converge, and so the limit in question is undefined.